# Track background location in webapp (service worker)

Tags: javascript, web-applications, geolocation, service-worker

I'm wondering if it is possible to track location while a Webapp is backgrounded?

I've heard this functionality is in the pipeline for service workers, though I can't find any literature on exactly how to do it.

It would be fine to just save the location on the phone until the phone is unlocked and then send location data over a network when the user re-opens the browser/tab.

If it isn't possible with purely Web technologies, what would be the best way to do this. Could one build a native app to handle tracking capability and still have a Web interface as the main UI?

**A bit of context**

I'm developing an app for a charity that allows users to track themselves when out and about etc.. The users are likely to lock their phones when on patrol so I need to account for this. I've built the majority of the app as a Webapp and it would be an big (and boring) task to rewrite it as a native android and apple app!

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible for privacy reasons. You also cannot do any sort of accurate scheduling via the Service Workers when the app is in the background, eg. use setTimeout or so (throttled by the browser).

You've probably read about the background sync API which allows you to ask the Service Worker to submit some data when a connection is available. With this API you can implement retry for form POSTs and stuff like that but not have the location tracked. Find out more here: https://davidwalsh.name/background-sync